# Initializing a particular class member in an Array List

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class

```
public class BeanTitle 
{
    private String btitle;

    public String getBtitle() {
        return btitle;
    }

    public void setBtitle(String btitle) {
        this.btitle = btitle;
    }

}
```

In another class I am creating an ArrayList of BeanTitle Type and trying to initialize the "btitle"..

```
class xyz
{
   void someMethod()
   {
       ArrayList<BeanTitle> bt=new ArrayList<BeanTitle>();
       ... // How to initialize each "btitle" member here?
   }
}
```

I am unsure of how to achieve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a new `BeanTitle` object, set the field with the setter, and then add it to your list, like this:

```
BeanTitle b = new BeanTitle();
b.setBtitle("Jeff");
bt.add(b);
```

Comment: Thanx a zillion!
Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
       ArrayList<BeanTitle> bt=new ArrayList<BeanTitle>();
       BeanTitle beanTitle = new BeanTitle();
       beanTitle.setBtitle("btitle");
       bt.add(beanTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the `BeanTitle` object.

You may use a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) in your `BeanTitle` object if you want.

```
public BeanTitle(String b){
  btitle = b;
}
```

Then you can create a new `BeanTitle` in `someMethod()`

```
ArrayList<BeanTitle> bt = new ArrayList<BeanTitle>();

//if you used a constructor
BeanTitle btObj = new BeanTitle("BTitle");


//otherwise use
BeanTitle btObj = new BeanTitle();
btObj.setBtitle("BTitle");

bt.add(ntObj);
```

Learn about [ArrayList.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) and [creating objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Answer (score 0):

You would add new items to your list using bt.add (theNewItem). Just set the btitle of each item before adding it to the list. (Or after, I suppose.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Collections` `fill` method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#fill(java.util.List,%20T)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#fill(java.util.List,%20T)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#fill(java.util.List,%20T)

```
int SIZE = 50;
ArrayList<BeatTitle> bt = new ArrayList<BeanTitle>(SIZE);
Collections.fill(bt, new BeanTitle());
```